# SSIS Catalog - Powershell - Access Package Variables

Tags: sql-server, powershell, ssis, sql-server-2014, ssis-2014

As the title suggests, I’m looking to get access to the variables in a package, when it is stored in the SSIS Catalog, using powershell. The reason I’m looking to do this is that Package Variables allow me to initialise and pass objects from powershell to the SSIS script (Project Parameters and Environment Variables in the SSIS Catalog cannot have parameters/variables of type Object)

If the package is stored in the old Integration Services store (folders within the MSDB database) I can access the variables using the ManagedDTS objects.

Using the new IntegrationServices package, which is the provided way to interact with packages in the SSIS Catalog in powershell, I can’t seem to find a way to access these variables.

Is there a way to access these variables, using powershell if the SSIS project is stored in the SSIS Catalog?

Comment: SSIS Packages are encrypted within the SSISDB; you cannot access the data within them. Perhaps the better question is, what are you trying to achieve here; why do you need a `object` as a parameter?

Comment: @Larnu I’m manipulating an Excel file with powershell objects, passing an ADO Recordset object of a derived result set (collated from disperse data in the excel file), triggering an SSIS package to load the file into SQL Server, manipulating the result using a variety of SQL operations, querying the results of those operations, and inserting the results of those operations back into excel, and notifying the user at the end.

Comment: The reason I’m doing this is because the standard SSIS method for interfacing with Excel (the ACE ADODB engine) is sub optimal due to how it guesses the data types for each column (its manageable in importing, but especially when extracting the data type guessing makes extracts unpredictable)

Comment: I agree that the ACE drivers are awful, however, that's why I therefore avoid using an Excel document as much as possible and will use a csv, or similar; where I'm then in control. Alternatively, if it's not a wide spreadsheet, you could create script component (not task) as your Dataflow's source instead to read the Excel File. You have far more control then, as you can override the ACE driver's (poor) decisions